# contrast matrix for NLS in R

Tags: r, nls

I am using NLS package for non linear regression in R. I am dealing with qualitative variables. What is the best way to incorporate the qualitative variable?

My solution so far:

```
df <- data.frame(height= c(185,187,190, 167,165,153),
       weight= c(88,75,93, 73,77, 61),
       gender=c("M","M","M","F","F", "F"))

contrast_matrix_for_gender <- data.frame(contrasts(as.factor(df[,3])))
contrast_matrix_for_gender[,2] <- rownames(contrast_matrix_for_gender )

df <- merge(x= df,
  y=contrast_matrix_for_gender,
  by.x=c("gender"),
  by.y=c("V2"),
  all.x=TRUE)

df.1 <- as.matrix( df[,2:4])

nls(df.1[,1] ~ 0 + a* df.1[,2] + b*df.1[,3], start = list(a=0, b=0))
```

Comment: The example given is just a linear regression

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure of what you are doing but the formula you gave is just a linear equation. This is what you are trying to do:

```
df1 <- data.frame(model.matrix(~ height + weight + gender + 0, df))
nls(height ~ a * weight + b * genderF + c * genderM, df1, list(a=0, b=0, c=0))
Nonlinear regression model
  model: height ~ a * weight + b * genderF + c * genderM
   data: data.frame(model.matrix(~height + weight + gender + 0, df))
       a        b        c 
  0.4336 131.1688 150.3312 
 residual sum-of-squares: 68.79
```

This is just a linear regression since you have `y = XB`. Thus you could do:

```
lm(height ~ weight + gender + 0, df)

Call:
lm(formula = height ~ weight + gender + 0, data = df)

Coefficients:
  weight   genderF   genderM  
  0.4336  131.1688  150.3312
```

As you can see, all the coefficients are exactly the same.

You will have non-linear least squares if you have formulas like `y=x^a + exp(b*x)` etc. But in your case you just have a linear model `y = a*x1 + b*x2...`